# End If without block If - double For Each loop

Tags: vba, for-loop, each

I'm trying to put some code together to do some simple calculations but am struggling to get past the If statements, they don't seem to make sense to me but my formatting is the same as solutions I've read to similar problems.

I'm getting the "End If without block If" on the final End If of the following:

```
Sub SAP1C()

Dim i1, j1 As Range
Dim Material, Customer, Price As String
Dim MaterialStart, CustomerStart, PriceStart As Object
Dim Counter As Integer

Set i1 = Sheets("Invoice Prices").Range("B1:RL1")
Set j1 = Sheets("Invoice Prices").Range("A6:A500")

Set PriceStart = Sheets("SAP 1C").Range("A3")
Set MaterialStart = Sheets("SAP 1C").Range("J3")
Set CustomerStart = Sheets("SAP 1C").Range("I3")

Counter = 0

For Each i In i1

    If i = "" Then Exit Sub Else

        For Each j In j1

            If j <> "" Then

                Price = Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Row(j), Application.WorksheetFunction.Column(i)).Value
                Material = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(j, Sheets("BTS").Range("F:G"), 2, 0)
                Customer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(i, Sheets("Customer Hub").Range("A:G"), 7, 0), "0000000000")

                PriceStart.Offset(Counter, 0) = Price
                MaterialStart.Offset(Counter, 0) = Material
                CustomerStart.Offset(Counter, 0) = Customer

                Counter = Counter + 1

            End If

        Next j

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

I've played with the code a little and can't quite figure it out - any ideas?
Thanks!

EDIT: Answered below - thank you very much!

I've changed the code slightly and fiddled with it to try and get it to work beyond the original problem but I'm hitting errors. Could you please take a look at the below?:

```
Sub SAP1C()

Dim i1, j1 As Range
Dim Material, Customer, Price As String
Dim MaterialStart, CustomerStart, PriceStart As Object
Dim Counter As Integer

Set i1 = Sheets("Invoice Prices").Range("B1:RL1")
Set j1 = Sheets("Invoice Prices").Range("A6:A300")

Set PriceStart = Sheets("SAP 1C").Range("A3")
Set MaterialStart = Sheets("SAP 1C").Range("J3")
Set CustomerStart = Sheets("SAP 1C").Range("I3")

Counter = 0

For Each i In i1

    If i = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else

        For Each j In j1

            If j <> "" Then

                If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(Sheets("Invoice Prices").Cells(j.Row, i.Column)) Then
                    Price = "POA"
                ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsErr(Sheets("Invoice Prices").Cells(j.Row, i.Column)) Then
                    Price = "POA"
                Else
                    Price = Round(Sheets("Invoice Prices").Cells(j.Row, i.Column).Value, 1)

                Material = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(j, Sheets("BTS").Range("F:G"), 2, 0)
                Customer = "00" & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(i, Sheets("Customer Hub").Range("A:G"), 7, 0)

                PriceStart.Offset(Counter, 0) = Price
                MaterialStart.Offset(Counter, 0) = Material
                CustomerStart.Offset(Counter, 0) = Customer

                Counter = Counter + 1

            End If

        Next j

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

"Next without For" on "Next j"? How does this work exactly? My Ifs all have End Ifs or seem to all close in some way, also my For Each's all have Next's. Everything seems to flow logically so I'm really confused as to what I'm missing here. Thanks!

Comment: mmh not sure about those `Next j` and `Next i` shouldn't those simply be `Next`?

Comment: `Next <iterated variable here>` is fine syntax for VBA. its more verbose but helps with readability on highly nested code

Comment: @DavidColwell right, new stuff learnt today, yay o/

Comment: Thanks very much for your replies - I used Next i and Next j because its a little easier to read but to be honest I didn't know it could just be "Next". I've updated my question as I'm hitting a different error below the original which is now sorted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Split out the lines on your first if like this

```
    If i = "" Then
      Exit Sub
    Else
    'other code
```

The VBA script environment treats your first if statement as an Inline If, meaning it tries to evaluate the else statement as whatever is left in the line (nothing).

Comment: @FunThomas 100% correct, and it avoids the Arrow Antipattern, but i thought i would elaborate on the reason it was happening, since its a quirk of the VBA script environment that it lets empty else statements dangle when they are part of an inline conditional

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to comment. I've made this change and the compiler seems happy to continue past this section, but I'm now having trouble with the next part - I'm getting "Next without For" and I'm not sure why! Not sure about StackOverflow etiquette but I'll edit my question to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

In your updated code, you are missing an `End If` after the command `Price = ...`

The syntax of an `If` is:

- Either use an one-line statement
- or you have to use `End If`

Examples:

```
If i = "" Then Exit Sub    ' no end if needed
```

This is equivalent to

```
If i = "" Then
    Exit Sub 
End if
```

Same is true when using `Else` (and `ElseIf`)

```
If i = "" Then Debug.print "empty" Else Debug.print i    

If i = "" Then
    Debug.print "empty"
Else
    Debug.print i 
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like as below.

Note that I have changed your declaration statements so you don't declare things as variants implicitly. For example:

```
Dim i1, j1 As Range
```

i1 is a Variant and only j1 is a Range.

I have also used `IsEmpty` test on cell and and used the `Worksheets` collection rather than `Sheets`.

Todo:

Put some error handling in for `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` not returning a match.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SAP1C()

    Dim i1 As Range, j1 As Range, i As Range, j As Range
    Dim Material As String, Customer As String, Price As String
    Dim MaterialStart As Object, CustomerStart As Object, PriceStart As Object
    Dim Counter As Long

    Set i1 = Sheets("Invoice Prices").Range("B1:RL1")
    Set j1 = Sheets("Invoice Prices").Range("A6:A300")

    Set PriceStart = Sheets("SAP 1C").Range("A3")
    Set MaterialStart = Sheets("SAP 1C").Range("J3")
    Set CustomerStart = Sheets("SAP 1C").Range("I3")

    Counter = 0

    For Each i In i1

        If IsEmpty(i) Then
            Exit Sub
        Else

            For Each j In j1

                If Not IsEmpty(j) Then

                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(Worksheets("Invoice Prices").Cells(j.Row, i.Column)) Then
                        Price = "POA"
                    ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsErr(Worksheets("Invoice Prices").Cells(j.Row, i.Column)) Then
                        Price = "POA"
                    Else
                        Price = Round(Worksheets("Invoice Prices").Cells(j.Row, i.Column).Value, 1)

                        Material = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(j, Worksheets("BTS").Range("F:G"), 2, 0)
                        Customer = "00" & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(i, Worksheets("Customer Hub").Range("A:G"), 7, 0)

                        PriceStart.Offset(Counter, 0) = Price
                        MaterialStart.Offset(Counter, 0) = Material
                        CustomerStart.Offset(Counter, 0) = Customer

                        Counter = Counter + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```